# how I can use (excel /database /sheets ) for calculation in Matlab App designer?

Tags: matlab

I have a great  database excel (several table in a single Excel sheet) and I want to use it for calculation in Matlab App designer,
my question is how can I get my data from this database (Excel) and use them on Matlab App designer,
MY solution is:
- I stored these table in Matlab as variable cell array , and I want every time I need a data I will go to find these variables.
Unfortunately my solution does not work, that's why I come to you to solicit you, give me an idea?
(how to use an excel static database file for calculations in matlab (app designer)
thanks in advance.

Comment: Why does your solution not work? Could you describe your problems?

Comment: I suggest you use `readtable` to import the Excel worksheet when your app starts.

Comment: To add @MikeLimaOscar comment, `readtable` accepts additional key-value pairs `Sheet` and `Range` to allow you to specify what data you want to import from the excel file. See the official docs for `readtable` by typing `doc readtable`.

Comment: I thank you for the answer , I will looking for after

Comment: my problem is that I can not get the cells of the tables stored forms of variable on Matlab from App designer by browsing the tables,